# Why does loadedmetadata not consistently fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know why loadedmetadata doesn't consistently fire on chrome. 
If you take this page and keep refreshing while inspecting the console you will see that only like 1 out 3 times it fires.

http://output.jsbin.com/petefipepa

js code looks like below

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#myvideo').on('loadedmetadata', function() {
      console.log('loadedmetadata');
  });
});
```

Comment: I dont really know the reason .. but another code works http://jsbin.com/cutoholare/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loadedmetadata event is something like the xhr onreadystatechange, it's checked periodically and during the period a certain amount of data has been loaded, it could be the whole package or just the headers.

https://dev.opera.com/articles/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video/
You can read more there.

Answer (score 4):

It may be a little late, but if anyone is still looking for the answer, I found a nice solution.

The "loadedmetadata" listener doesn't fire because the audio has already been loaded when the listener is added.

I'm trying to be more clear.
Audios when loaded by the browser have different states (readyState):

0. HAVE_NOTHING
1. HAVE_METADATA
2. HAVE_CURRENT_DATA
3. HAVE_FUTURE_DATA
4. HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA

[Mozilla Documentation about readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState)

When we add the listener

```
$('#audioOrVideo').on('loadedmetadata', function() {});
```

We wait for the transition from state 0 to state 1 to occur.

Imagine that an audio is put at the beginning of the page and during the loading of the document it quickly loads. The audio goes from state 0 to a state greater than 0, and then we add the listener.

Our listener will never receive the event because it occurred before the listener was even added.

I propose a solution that has worked for me.

```
var audioOrVideo = document.getElementById('audioOrVideoElement');
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Attendiamo che venga caricato l'audio
        if (audioOrVideo.readyState > 0) {
            //code
        } else {
            audioOrVideo.on("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
                //code
            });
        };
    });
```